# How to convert Objective-C to C language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compilation

In C programming, if a method is not defined, there will be error,
while in objective-C programming, there will only be warning.
Why?
For example, `[object method]`, how it be compiled?

Comment: Because Objective-C is a dynamic language.  You might want to read more about Objective-C on Apple's Doc.

Comment: Turn on "treat warnings as errors" and it'll be an error.   Warnings as errors is a good idea anyway;  you should not have any warnings in your code.

Answer (score 4):

`[object method]` compiles to 'pass the message, 'method' to 'object''.

At runtime `object` will first check whether it has a method with the name of the message. If it does then it'll perform it. Otherwise there are various backup mechanisms for forwarding the message to someone else or inventing a response based on the name.

What `[object method]` explicitly doesn't compile to is a C++-style name mangling like `__objectClass_Method@4(object)` or whatever. In C terms it'll compile to an invocation of `objc_msgSend` which definitely exists because it's defined by the runtime.

Beyond Objective-C, dynamic dispatch is also used by languages such as JavaScript, Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Tommy's answer is absolutely correct. But you can treat your warnings as error in project settings 
 
[image]